# Custom font does not appear in emulator WP8

Tags: xaml, button, windows-phone-8, font-family, custom-font

I am trying to customize my button style and use custom font. I tried placing this in the setter property

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/Assets/garfield.ttf#GARFIELD the CAT" />
```

but I get

```
The type 'Setter' does not support direct content.
```

Using the following in my XAML displayed the font properly in the Design window but in the emulator it just showed the standard font.

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" FontFamily="/Assets/garfield.ttf#GARFIELD the CAT" Content="Play" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
```

How to use custom font in the button control for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Have you tried maybe applying it directly to the ContentControl/ContentPresenter in the button style template itself?

Comment: Not yet. Not sure how to do that. Can you give an example? Thanks